# Dynamically executing and terminating external programs with C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, execve, external-application

I need to execute processes with still being in control of each process.
I want to create a class which stores the threads or pids or what ever is necessary to do so.

I currently have a program which executes one external application with the C function execvp and also loads the environment from a shell script. So my current program is blocking. But I need to be able to keep it freely running and only by time I terminate a currently running or start a new external application.

My current approach would be to create a thread, which uses the execve function. But then the thread would be blocking as far as I can see.

The code which might be in the thread (with variables then):

```
char *argv[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "myApplication", 0 };
execve(argv[0], &argv[0], environment.data());
```

The applications called are probably not fixed in the code their names will be given by an external setup file, including parameters.

Now my actual question, is there a better way to "manage" external applications like that in c++? Some ready solution (class, library)? And if not how do I terminate the thread if this is the actual way. Using the terminate call is said to be bad practice, that's what I often read.

I hope this is now specific enough for the forum, because I do not know how to get more specific anymore. If you need more hints what I want to create here, feel free to ask in the comments.

**Update**:

to DBus & others:

Additional information I do not wrote all of the processes I want to start!
So it will be used to start 3rd party applications, which even if I have the code, do **not** want to change.

Comment: You want to read about fork-exec model and waitpid. Don't bother with threads, they are not the right tool for the job.

Comment: C++ does not know what a process is. So, no, there is no standard C++ facility available.

Comment: Are you really sure with the threads?
When I think about it makes more sense, not copying the whole application (like fork does). And I can easily manage it and terminate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `fork()` before you exec. `fork()` is a function that creates a new process *identical* to the original caller of `fork()` running as a subprocess. The difference is that the parent process gets the child's pid as a return value and the child gets 0. The gist of what you want to do is this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if( pid == 0 )
{
    // we're the child process
    char *argv[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "myApplication", 0 };
    int rc = execve(argv[0], &argv[0], environment.data());
    // execve only returns if there was an error
    // check 'errno' and handle it here
}
else if ( pid < 0 )
{
    // pid is less than zero, we didn't successfully fork,
    // there is no child process.
    throw "error message";
}

// do whatever processing the parent does
```

More info is [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html). The `kill()` function isn't bad practice per se, if you want to quickly and gracefully end the subprocess you *can* write signal handlers in it, but you should be using something like [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) or [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) to do proper interprocess communication. You want to tell the program to do something, not just tell it to die (usually what you want it to do if you're killing it).

Comment: Hmm, but when I use fork, then the whole application(with all it's current state) would be cloned completely. Currently for my implementation,I guess that would not be a problem ... but when I imagine that I have a "main" process, hosting a lot of data in the memory, then the memory contents, would also be cloned...  Am I right with that? Somehow that fact that I get a copy of the whole application with fork() gives me headaches ... To dbus etc. how to communicate with a process you do not have written? Doesn't dbus require to be the developer of the application? I add that to my question.

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: You are misunderstanding. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) it has several chapters to explain all that.

Comment: Using that now, but with vfork instead of fork. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**NEVER USE `execv` functions in threads** because the execve() system call overlays the current **process** image with a new process image.

The correct pattern if fork-exec or better vfork-exec. Extract from the manpage:

*The vfork() system call can be used to create new processes without fully
     copying the address space of the old process, which is horrendously inefficient in a paged environment.  It is useful when the purpose of fork(2)
     would have been to create a new system context for an execve(2).  The
     vfork() system call differs from fork(2) in that the child borrows the
     parent's memory and thread of control until a call to execve(2) or an
     exit (either by a call to _exit(2) or abnormally).  The parent process is
     suspended while the child is using its resources.*

Using `vfork` shortly followed with `execve`, you avoid the copy of the original process image, and do not erase if with the new process, so the original process has the pid of its child and cat control it, look whether it has ended, send it signals and so on.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I wasn't aware of that with the threads.